# How to remove multiple object from the list at the same time

Tags: python, arrays

```
w = [1, 2, 3, -3, -2, 4, -4, 1, 2, -2]


def data_remover(xarray, ind):
    for i in ind:
        del xarray[i]
    return xarray


print(data_remover(w, [2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9]))
```

I am trying to write a code such that it removes adjacent (+n, -n) pairs such as (3,-3) (4,-4) etc.

However I cannot use `del[i]` since when I remove an element the xarray also changes. I tried to use `deepcopy` to copy the x array but I couldnt manage to run the code.

```
from copy import deepcopy

w = [1, 2, 3, -3, -2, 4, -4, 1, 2, -2]


def data_remover(xarray, ind):
    xcopy = deepcopy(xarray)
    for i in ind:
        del xarray[i]
    return xarray


print(data_remover(w, [2, 3]))
```

Comment: If you are reading from left to right, if you delete +n at position i, then -n will automatically be there at position i. just perform two delete calls at i.

Comment: Did you try getting a copy before the data_remover function? Like `temp = w`, then `data_remover(temp, [2, 3])`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove items from a list while iterating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating)

Comment: @anvoice with Python doing `temp = w` doesn't achieve nothing at all... You just get another reference to the same list object...

Comment: meant that as temp = w[:]... Need to get some sleep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort the list of indices in descending order so that deleting an element will not effect the position of another. You can do this by `reversed(ind)`

```
w = [1, 2, 3, -3, -2, 4, -4, 1, 2, -2] 
def data_remover(xarray, ind):
    for i in reversed(ind):
         del xarray[i] 
    return xarray 
print(data_remover(w, [2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9]))
```

Or if your indices are not in any order you can always sort them in descending order.

```
for i in sorted(ind, reverse = True):
```

Comment: very clever solution

Comment: this is really spicy, but if you're planning for other people to read your code, please go with Ron's answer

Comment: @ddg why? And I hope you mean his second suggestion...

Comment: It's just late at night and I'm being dramatic. When I'm scanning the function, the notable words are "for" "reversed" "del". The usage of "reversed" feels like a red herring, because it has no conceptual relation to the problem and only exists to step around an implementation detail. As someone reading code, it takes me about 3x longer to parse than a simple list comprehension.

Comment: @ddg That is indeed a very good point! I agree

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways I can think of

Assuming the list of indices to remove is sorted Either set a variable to keep track of deletions

```
def data_remover(xarray, ind):
    removed_count = 0
    for i in ind:
        del xarray[i - removed_count]
        removed_count +=1
    return xarray
```

Or create a new list

```
def data_remover(xarray, ind):
    return [item for i, item in enumerate(xarray) if i not in ind]
```

Answer (score 1):

The question [How to remove items from a list while iterating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating) already has many solutions for this problem. In your case, the simplest solution will be to iterate the indexes from the end, that way you're not affecting the next deletions and the indexes stay correct in all iterations. So just change the loop to:

```
for i in ind[::-1]:
```

---

Example run:

```
def data_remover(xarray, ind):
    print(xarray)
    for i in ind[::-1]:
        print(f"deleting {xarray[i]} from index {i},", end='')
        del xarray[i]
        print(f" gives - {xarray}")
    return xarray

print(data_remover([1, 2, 3, -3, -2, 4, -4, 1, 2, -2], [2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9]))
```

Gives:

```
Initial -                         [1, 2, 3, -3, -2, 4, -4, 1, 2, -2]
deleting -2 from index 9, gives - [1, 2, 3, -3, -2, 4, -4, 1, 2]
deleting  2 from index 8, gives - [1, 2, 3, -3, -2, 4, -4, 1]
deleting -4 from index 6, gives - [1, 2, 3, -3, -2, 4, 1]
deleting  4 from index 5, gives - [1, 2, 3, -3, -2, 1]
deleting -3 from index 3, gives - [1, 2, 3, -2, 1]
deleting  3 from index 2, gives - [1, 2, -2, 1]
Final -                           [1, 2, -2, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sidestep having to remove at multiple indices. To remove adjacent inverses (3, -3) in one pass, I would do something like:

```
data = [1, 2, 3, -3, -2, 4, -4, 1, 2, -2]

location = 0  # start at 0
temp = []  # new array that you're building

while location < len(data):
    if data[location] == -data[location+1]:
        location += 2  # inverses, skip them!
    else:
        temp.append(data[location])
        location += 1

data = temp
```